# Use Function From Earlier in Function Path

Tags: linux, shell, fish, aliases

In `fish`, is it possible to reference or use a function inside another function of the same name? For example, `fish` has a function `ls` at `/usr/local/share/functions/ls.fish`, which sets some default parameters based on things like OS and whether the shell has colors. I want to define another function that will set some default colors for me without clobbering this other function in case I want to use a newer version of `fish`.

The easiest way to set an alias seems to be to use `command`, like so:

```
function ls
    command ls -F $argv
end
```

in the file `ls.fish` in the folder `~/.config/fish/functions`. This is the default folder for user-defined functions. Both this folder and `~/.config/fish/functions` are in `$fish_function_path`, but `~/.config/fish/functions` comes later so users can set their own functions which override `fish`'s default functions. However, as the `fish` documentation says,

```
command forces the shell to execute the program COMMANDNAME and ignore
any functions or builtins with the same name.
```

**How do I override an alias/function with one defined later in `$fish_function_path`, without over*writing* it?** Ideally, solutions would also use the built-in command of the same name, like `cd`, as according to the cited documentation that is not possible, either, but this is not required.

Finally, is this a good idea? If `fish` does not do this by default, there must be a reason, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual trick is to copy the function you want to override, and then invoke the copy from within the override:

```
functions --copy ls saved_ls
function ls
    saved_ls
end
```

You can't do this in an autoloading `ls.fish` file since it would result in an infinite loop, but you can do it in `config.fish`.

Comment: Why would this result in an infinite loop? The `~/.config/fish/functions/ls.fish` file is invoked *after* the `/usr/local/share/fish/functions/ls.fish` file, correct? Or are they both invoked at the same time and functions defined in the former file override ones in the latter file, but both are called at the same time when running the command?

Comment: It sources only the first `ls.fish` found by searching `$fish_function_path`. So the one in `~/.config` will mask the one in `/usr/local/share`. The reason it results in an infinite loop is that executing `ls.fish` first tries to copy `ls`, which means autoloading `ls`, which means executing `ls.fish`...

Comment: Got it, thanks. That might be information to put in the docs, assuming it isn't already there and I'm blind and didn't see it.